# Trying to code a quarkus camel awssqs consumer

Tags: java, apache-camel, amazon-sqs, quarkus

I am trying to write my first little quarkus camel AWSSQS consumer and I just can't find any (simple or otherwise) examples to start off with.

I have generated a skeleton app via the quarkus.io webpage and I've created a route to just consume the JSON off of my SQS queue (the queue is created and populated with messages and I can consume them with "raw" java).

It is a fifo queue containing JSON test messages.

My routebuilder class is as follows:

```
package sun.java.tester.quarkus.camel.sqs;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

/**
 *
 * @author ELMARM
 */
public class MyRouteBuilder  extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("aws2-sqs://JSONTestQ.fifo?accessKey=AKIAYAKVQFZGTCDOR3OP&secretKey=yyyyy&region=us-east-2")
            .log("We have a message! ${body}")
            .to("file:target/output?fileName=tester-message-${date:now:MMDDyy-HHmmss}.json");
    
}
```

When I start the quarkus application I get the following error:

> 2021-08-23 15:04:06,630 ERROR [org.apa.cam.qua.mai.CamelMainRuntime]
> (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application:
> org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route
> route1:
> Route(route1)[From[aws2-sqs://JSONTestQ.fifo?accessKey=AKIAY...
> because of Failed to resolve endpoint:
> aws2-sqs://JSONTestQ.fifo?accessKey=AKIAYAKVQFZGTCDOR3OP&region=us-east-2&secretKey=xxxxxx
> due to: The request signature we calculated does not match the
> signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing
> method. Consult the service documentation for details.
>
> The Canonical String for this request should have been 'POST /
>
> amz-sdk-invocation-id:9f2e22b6-3d08-2dc2-e45e-643e84ba6437
> amz-sdk-request:attempt=1; max=3 content-length:36
> content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
> host:sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com x-amz-date:20210823T130405Z
>
> amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date
> 48a38266faf90970d6c7fea9b15e6ba366e5f6397c2970fc893f8a7b5e207bd0'
>
> The String-to-Sign should have been 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 20210823T130405Z
> 20210823/us-east-2/sqs/aws4_request
> 07d49a70f6163cd5d0bbb21d1b3e2a8c1927feb3ec4ddbd7fcbc768f3e994189'
> (Service: Sqs, Status Code: 403, Request ID:
> fe69821c-e9be-5250-b428-db8176b8c0c2, Extended Request ID: null)
> at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:80)
> at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModelReifierFactory.createRoute(DefaultModelReifierFactory.java:49)
> at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:826)
> at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:716)
> at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doInit(AbstractCamelContext.java:2756)
> at org.apache.camel.quarkus.core.FastCamelContext.doInit(FastCamelContext.java:158)
> at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.init(BaseService.java:83)
> at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.init(AbstractCamelContext.java:2475)
> at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:111)
> at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2494)
> at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:245)
> at org.apache.camel.quarkus.main.CamelMain.doStart(CamelMain.java:94)
> at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
> at org.apache.camel.quarkus.main.CamelMain.startEngine(CamelMain.java:139)
> at org.apache.camel.quarkus.main.CamelMainRuntime.start(CamelMainRuntime.java:49)
> at org.apache.camel.quarkus.core.CamelBootstrapRecorder.start(CamelBootstrapRecorder.java:45)
> at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.CamelBootstrapProcessor$boot-173480958.deploy_0(CamelBootstrapProcessor$boot-173480958.zig:101)
> at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.CamelBootstrapProcessor$boot-173480958.deploy(CamelBootstrapProcessor$boot-173480958.zig:40)
> at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(ApplicationImpl.zig:898)
> at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
> at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:101)
> at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:66)
> at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:42)
> at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:119)
> at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(GeneratedMain.zig:29)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:98)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve
> endpoint:
> aws2-sqs://JSONTestQ.fifo?accessKey=AKIAYAKVQFZGTCDOR3OP&region=us-east-2&secretKey=xxxxxx
> due to: The request signature we calculated does not match the
> signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing
> method. Consult the service documentation for details.

I've checked and my accessKey and secretKey are correct as my "raw" java program can consume the messages.

I'm VERY green with quarkus (and even more so with camel), so any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Elmar

Answer (score 0):

The 'from' endpoint URI scheme should be `aws2-sqs`. E.g:

```
from("aws-sqs2://JSONTestQ.fifo?region=us-east-2?useDefaultCredentialsProvider")
```

See the URI format section in the documentation:

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.11.x/aws2-sqs-component.html.

Comment: Thanks James. That seems to have solved that problem (My example that I had was obviously bad). I've changed my question now to reflect the current (new) problem I'm getting.  I've "hardcoded" the access and secret key (and the region) in the from part of the camel call, but it seems SQS has some issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after MUCH trail and tribulations, it turns out that the secret key had "special" characters in (i.e. a +) and for that you have to put a RAW around your secret key parameter.

So my route now looks as follows:

```
from("aws2-sqs://JSONTestQ.fifo?accessKey=AKIAYAKVQFZGTCDOR3OP&secretKey=RAW(xxxx+xxxxx)&region=us-east-2")
            .log("We have a message! ${body}")
            .to("file://target/output?fileName=tester-message-${date:now:MMDDyy-HHmmss}.json");
```

And that has done the trick. I now receive my messages and store them in a .json file.